# Remove place holder image from a div once dynamic content has been added to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have a div acting as a container that when empty shows an image, and I want to remove that image when content gets added to the container dynamically, what would be the best Jquery method to accomplish this? Doing the usual -

```
 if ($(".container").html().length <= 0) {
    $('.ad').show();
 }
```

does not work in this case since the content being added is dynamic and does not involve a refresh. I tried storing the check in in a setIntercal function that would run every 100ms but the results didn't turn out as expected and it also caused some odd flickering on the page.

EDIT**

Josh Burgess' method would be the one I use in all cases if I didn't have to support IE8. Because of this I'm going to fall back to adding a .hide() method on the  when the click event for adding content is fired. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are you adding the content? If the image is just an `<img>` tag in the div, wouldn't it be automatically replaced by the new content?

Comment: What about calling that code when you update the content?

Comment: @Stavros_S The function that calls when the *dynamic content* get added, is the point in which you should check whether the to hide/show your placeholder image.

Comment: If you have access to the function that changes the content, you can remove the image there.  Or you can set a create a trigger event that is called when the content is changed (again, you have to call that trigger from the function replacing the content).

Comment: Yea one of my thoughts is to just hide the <img> when the click event fires that adds the content. But I feel if down the road we allow that content to be removed dynamically as well then this would not allow the add to re-appear if the container is empty again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use jQuery at all?

Try this CSS:

```
div.myDiv:empty{
  background-image: url(path/to/myimage);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

div.myDiv {
  background-image: none;
  height:auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

**--EDIT--**

[Here's a working example in jsfiddle, and it works in reverse as well](http://jsfiddle.net/4raMR/1/)

Comment: Will give it a shot, although I didn't think something like this would work when content is added to the container dynamically.

Comment: @Stavros_S Check it, it totally does.  I just put a fiddle up for it.  Bam.

Comment: Thanks for the example it does work out for, unfortunately I need to support IE8 though which does not support the :empty selector. I will give you the answer any way though since I didn't make that evident. Thanks!